# Не получается в NGINX принять POST запрос в формате JSON

Tags: nginx, сервер

Мучаюсь уже много времени с проблемой приема POST запроса на nginx , на локальном сервере все работает замечательно .на vps только GET работает уже прописал и заголовки и тд .но продвижения нет от слова совсем ,может есть какие то наработки по этому вопросу
вот конфиг nginx

`````
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name www.mydomain.ru mydomain.ru;


root /home/admin/web-app/arigato-app/dist/;
index index.php index.html index.nginx-debian.html;


ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/arigatosushi.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/arigatosushi.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
charset -utf8;


location/ {

if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,
Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';

add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
return 204;


}

if ($request_method = 'POST') {
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' "Content-Type ,Accept,Authorization,x-requested-with";
add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'origin-list';
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD';
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000';
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true';
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization';
more_set_headers 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8';
more_set_headers 'Content-Length: 0';
}
if ($request_method = 'GET') {
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';

}
location /api/ {

       default_type application/json;
       index db.json;
       alias /home/admin/web-app/arigato-app/src/assets/data/;
       include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

}
location /api/orderses {

#error_page 405 =200 /api/orderses/orders.json;

# proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 #   proxy_set_header Host $http_post;
  #   proxy_redirect off;
 rewrite ^/orders.json(.*) $1 break;
access_log /etc/nginx/sites-available/orders.log  json_log;
 log_format json_log   $request_body;
      #  access_log  /var/www/orders.json;
       default_type application/json;
      # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'origin-list';
      index orders.json;
     alias /home/admin/web-app/arigato-app/src/assets/orderbase/;
     #   include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
#error_page 405 =200 $uri;
}````
`````